# How to insert the values from the list into SQL table?

Tags: sql, qt

I have a SQL database and I am able to read/write it using the `QSqlTableModel`. Now I have created a list and have inserted values into it. Upon clicking a push button I want the values in the list to be updated in the database. 
Your help will be very useful. Kindly help me modify the code.

```
Conndb conn;
conn.open();

QSqlQuery sql;
sql.prepare("insert into [ECUP_DSS_DB].[dbo].[ContHistory] (HistID, NodeID)"
            "values (?, ?)");

QVariantList Hidval;
Hidval << 2 << 2 << 1 << 8;
sql.addBindValue(Hidval);

QVariantList Nodeval;
Nodeval << 2 << 2 << 1 << 8;
sql.addBindValue(Nodeval);

// QSqlTableModel * modal = new QSqlTableModel();

if (!sql.execBatch()) {
    qDebug() << sql.lastError();
} else {
    qDebug() << sql.executedQuery();
}
QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
sql.exec();
modal->setQuery(sql);
ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
conn.close();
```

Comment: Keyword formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example to add several values in a batch looks as follows:

```
QVariantList values;
values << 1 << 2 << 3;

QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO numbers (number) VALUES(?)");
query.addBindValue(values);

if (!query.execBatch()) {
    qDebug() << query.lastError();
} else {
    qDebug() << query.executedQuery();
}
```

And setting up table view

```
QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery("SELECT id, number FROM numbers");
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

For this example I've used following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, number INTEGER);
```

Comment: I have a table with HistID, NodeID, SV_EXT and TIME_STAMP as headings. I wish to add rows to HistID and NodeID and display them in the QSqlTableModel. Seeing the above comment I have made changes in the coding but then too the table is not diplayed in the TableView. I have edited my code in the question.

Comment: I don't know if you missed type but you are using same `sql` object with insert statement for `execBatch` and for `exec` methods. Then you put it in `setQuery`?

Comment: Eventhough I comment out the sql.exec() statement I dont get the output. I dont get any error neither the desired output.

Comment: I get the following error. "Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] The column name or number of supplied values ​​does not match table definition [Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] Statement. (s) (s) could not be prepared. ""

Comment: OK. So what are the exact names for ContHistory? It seems that names of columns in select query have bad names.

Comment: Table name: ContHistory. Column names are HistID, NodeID, dataTypesID, MODE, SV_INT, SV_EXT, PV and TIME_STAMP. So in total the table has 8 columns.

Comment: Sometimes I get the error "IDENTITY INSERT IS OFF" and hence cannot add values to the identity column.

Comment: QODBCResult :: exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft] [SQL Native Client] [SQL Server] An explicit value for the identity column can not be inserted into the ContHistory table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: I have edited the prepare command in the code. But now I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: I think you should not insert values to HistID as those are generated by SQL server.

Comment: I dont think so .. Anyways I tried inserting it into the second column and I get this message. "Starte E:\ECUP3000\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe...
"insert into [ECUP_DSS_DB].[dbo].[ContHistory] (NodeID)values (?)"". But the values are not entered in the database nor they are displayed in the table view.

Comment: Maybe you should try with different database, like sqlite. There is no need to make any configuration for that. If simple example will work then it means that this is something MS SQL specific. Maybe it need explicit transaction or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. May be I will try using a different database.